# Card Layout and File List Conflict when Exported

Tags: java, eclipse, file, export, cardlayout

Ok, so i'm programming a flashcard desktop application as a school project. The program is pretty large by now, this is obviously grossly simplified. The way it's structured is that one can choose flashcard decks (in form of text files in a folder) from a list. So the program gets these text files and displays them and then later reads/rewrites these text files. Now this all works perfectly well in eclipse. However, when I export the project as a JAR file, run it and click on the buttons, nothing happens. The application doesn't flip to the next card.
I figure there are two problems here, one is the folder and file thing when converting to jar and the other is that it somehow messes up the cardlayout. Is there anyway around this? I just need to hand in a desktop application on a USB, is there still a way to do this?

```
package isolatedIssue;

// all my imports here.

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    JPanel contPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
    JList<String> list = new JList();
    CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();
    JButton button = new JButton("Click me.");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me again.");
    frame.add(contPanel);
    contPanel.setLayout(cardlayout);
    contPanel.add(mainPanel, "1");
    contPanel.add(secondPanel, "2");
    mainPanel.add(button);
    secondPanel.add(button2);
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setModel(listModel);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    File folder = new File("folder");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            listModel.add(i, listOfFiles[i].getName());

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cardlayout.show(contPanel, "2");
                }
            });
        }
    }


    secondPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list));

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardlayout.show(contPanel, "2");
        }
    });
    // second action listener to get back to the other panel omitted.
 }

}
```

I know this is a lot at once, I probably made a mistake in asking the question, im a noob etc etc but any help is greatly appreciated :) THANK YOU!!

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but the line `listModel.add(i, listOfFiles[i].getName());` looks suspicious. Let's say that `listOfFiles[0]` is a directory and you skip it. If `listOfFiles[1]` is a file, you are calling `listModel.add(1, listOfFiles[1].getName())`. However the listModel will be still empty so adding an element at position 1 will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You should be calling `listModel.addElement(...);` instead.

Comment: You are right that doenst make sense here, however in the larger application it does, because it makes it neater. Later the name is used and then the actual file is called.

Comment: Sorry if you misunterstood me. You should replace `listModel.add(i, listOfFiles[i].getName());`with `listModel.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());`. The first version will fail unexpectedly if there are subdirectories in your folder. And this is not about 'making it neater'. It's about robustness: code that works even if there are things in your folder that you don't expect.

Comment: Your problem is almost surely related to reading the files. If you did not set up the folder hierarchy properly in your project and did not use relative paths in your code, then when exporting to jar something will stop working. I best that if you run the jar from a command line you'll see exceptions thrown. This has nothing to do with card layout.